# Chain/Redirect AWS API Gateway custom authorizer without explicit invoke

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, proxy, authorization, aws-api-gateway

Is there any way of chaining custom authorizers in API Gateway without making an explicit invoke to another lambda?

Imagine like having an `authorizerA` that is in charge of the validation of the token of the request. Once, that authorizer validates that information, it will pass the request to an `authorizerB` that will validate something else. But `authorizerA` just "returns" to the API Gateway that the authorization request must be sent to another lambda or just fail if the validation of `authorizerA` fails and so on for multiple authorizers.

Is there any other approach that does not involve an invoke (that cost twice the waiting time for 2 authorizers or a lot for multiple authorizers)?

I haven't used step functions, but could this be a case for it?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, step function is your ally. You will need a lambda function to attach as an authorizer to your API Gateway. This lambda function will invoke the step function where all the magic should happen and then return the result back to the lambda authorizer so it can be returned to the API Gateway.